# MasterDetailPage Xamarin.Forms unable to pass Parameter on Navigation from Menu

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, navigation, parameter-passing, master-detail

I am using default MasterDetailPage template for my Xamarin multiple projects solution.

The code for MainPage is like so:

```
public partial class MainPage : MasterDetailPage
{

    public CompanyId _loggedInCompany;
    public string company { get; set; }

    Dictionary<int, NavigationPage> MenuPages = new Dictionary<int, NavigationPage>();
    public MainPage(CompanyId companyId)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        _loggedInCompany = companyId;
        company = _loggedInCompany.CompanyName;

        MasterBehavior = MasterBehavior.Popover;

        MenuPages.Add((int)MenuItemType.WelcomePage, (NavigationPage)Detail);
    }

    public async Task NavigateFromMenu(int id)
    {
        if (!MenuPages.ContainsKey(id))
        {
            switch (id)
            {
                case (int)MenuItemType.WelcomePage:
                    MenuPages.Add(id, new NavigationPage(new WelcomePage(company)));
                    break;
                case (int)MenuItemType.UsersPage:
                    MenuPages.Add(id, new NavigationPage(new UsersPage()));
                    break;
                case (int)MenuItemType.WebHomePage:
                    MenuPages.Add(id, new NavigationPage(new ClientHomePage()));
                    break;
                case (int)MenuItemType.VideosPage:
                    MenuPages.Add(id, new NavigationPage(new VideosPage()));
                    break;
                case (int)MenuItemType.SpecialPage1:
                    MenuPages.Add(id, new NavigationPage(new SpecialPage1()));
                    break;
                case (int)MenuItemType.SettingsPage:
                    MenuPages.Add(id, new NavigationPage(new SettingsPage()));
                    break;
            }
        }

        var newPage = MenuPages[id];

        if (newPage != null && Detail != newPage)
        {
            Detail = newPage;

            if (Device.RuntimePlatform == Device.Android)
                await Task.Delay(100);

            IsPresented = false;
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see on NavigatedFromMenu(int id), when navigating to WelcomePage I am trying to pass company string, but on build I get error:

> The given key was not present in the dictionary

What am I doing wrong here?

Without parameter passing the code works. Also, my WelcomePage accepts string like `WelcomePage(string company)`

Comment: "but on build I get error" - a build error should tell you which file and line is causing it.

Comment: It says Main page.xaml line 1

Comment: It says Main page.xaml line 1. Not much of help

Comment: if the error is in your XAML page perhaps you should post that?

Comment: It is connected to the cs part, to the parameter exactly as removing parameter does not cause error.

Comment: is the error a compiler error or a runtime exception?